# how to insert custom logs in app insights from azure function app?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I want to send custom logs to azure app insights from azure function app.
For eg i want to send error code error message and payload from azure functions to app insights

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. For these kind of question we do require you to first find out the options yourself and if you have specific questions you can ask a question. For this question there are plenty of [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#structured-logging) available.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

```
[FunctionName("MyFunc")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
   ...
   log.LogInformation($"Hello!");
```

For extra properties you can do the following:

```
var p = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
   ["MyExtraProperty1"] = 7
};

using var scope = log.BeginScope(p);
log.LogWarning("Oh no!");
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Enable AppInsights in Azure Portal

2.Get Instrumentation Key from Azure portal for AppInsights

3.Add key to local.settings.json:

```
"IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000"
  }
```